# EF 7 - Context returns null although values are there

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I have a CQRS setup and I am trying to use domain events.
After I receive a command for a new order, I am adding the newly created `Order` object to the `dbcontext`.

```cs
public async Task<Guid> Handle(CreateOrderCommand message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            
            ...

            var order = new Order(...);

            ...

            order.SubmitOrder();

            _orderRepository.Add(order);

            await _orderRepository.UnitOfWork
                .SaveEntitiesAsync(cancellationToken);

            return order.Id;
        }
```

The `order.SubmitOrder()` method is as follows

```cs
public void SubmitOrder()
    {
        AddDomainEvent(new OrderPlacedDomainEvent(Guid.NewGuid(), Id));
    }
```

and `orderRepository.UnitOfWork.SaveEntitiesAsync(cancellationToken);` is on overload to the `UnitOfWork.SaveEntitiesAsync()` as follows:

```cs
 public async Task<bool> SaveEntitiesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        // Dispatch Domain Events collection. 
        // Choices:
        // A) Right BEFORE committing data (EF SaveChanges) into the DB will make a single transaction including  
        // side effects from the domain event handlers which are using the same DbContext with "InstancePerLifetimeScope" or "scoped" lifetime
        // B) Right AFTER committing data (EF SaveChanges) into the DB will make multiple transactions. 
        // You will need to handle eventual consistency and compensatory actions in case of failures in any of the Handlers. 
        if (_mediator != null)
        {
            await _mediator.DispatchDomainEventsAsync(this);
        }

        // After executing this line all the changes (from the Command Handler and Domain Event Handlers) 
        // performed through the DbContext will be committed
        await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        return true;
    }
```

Note that the changes are not saved before the events are dispatched and the handler is called.

Now in the event handler when I am trying to get the order object from the context:

```cs
await _context.Orders.Include(o => o.OrderItems).SingleOrDefaultAsync(o => o.Id == id, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

it returns `null` although the data is available in the context under `_context.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView`

[image]

Is there any way to get the `order` data here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, solution found:

If `Find`/`FindAsync`is used instead of `SingleOrDefaultAsync` it will return the values available in the change tracker.

```cs
public async Task<Order?> FindAsync(Guid id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        =>  await _context.Orders.FindAsync(new object[] { id }, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```